# how can we show and hide tab using checkbox

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

what i am trying to do that when i click on checkbox 1 and checkbox 2 then show and hide its work fine

i want when i click on both checkbox 1 and 2 then colour toggle tab red green and blue its show in up front on the add new button and when click uncheck box2 then its hide colour toggle

how can we that in below code functionality works fine but

i want to achieve colour toggle tab bar is shown in upfront of the add new button .

any help in this its very thankful .
example image link https://kapwi.ng/w/DQu7aukF what i trying to achieve in my below code https://kapwi.ng/w/DQu7aukF  any one help me this

for reference image link what type i try to achieve image link example- https://ibb.co/6BWKS5c

```js
function addDay(e) {
  document.getElementById(e.value).style.display = e.checked ? "initial" : "none";
}
```

```css
.container-2{
display:flex}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <input type="checkbox" value="lundi" id="lundiCheck" onclick="addDay(this)" />1
  <input type="checkbox" value="mardi" id="mardiCheck" onclick="addDay(this)" />2
  <input type="checkbox" value="mercredi" id="mercrediCheck" onclick="addDay(this)" />3
  <input type="checkbox" value="jeudi" id="jeudiCheck" onclick="addDay(this)" />4
  <input type="checkbox" value="vendredi" id="vendrediCheck" onclick="addDay(this)" />5
  <input type="checkbox" value="samedi" id="samediCheck" onclick="addDay(this)" />6
  <input type="checkbox" value="dimanche" id="dimancheCheck" onclick="addDay(this)" />7
</div>

<div class="container-2">
  <div class="row mr-2 ml-0" style="display:none;" id="lundi">
  
    <br>
  <!-- Nav pills -->
  <ul class="nav nav-pills" role="tablist">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="pill" href="#homemade">variant</a>
    </li>
    
  </ul>

  <!-- Tab panes -->
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div id="homemade" class="container tab-pane active"><br>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">ADD NEW</button>
      
    </div>
      </div>
  
  
  
  </div>
  
  
  <div class="row mr-2 ml-0" style="display:none;" id="mardi">
      <br>
  <!-- Nav pills -->
  <ul class="nav nav-pills" role="tablist">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="pill" href="#home">Colors</a>
    </li>
   
   
  </ul>

  <!-- Tab panes -->
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div id="home" class="container tab-pane active"><br>
        <!-- Nav tabs -->
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="#home">Red</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1">Green</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#menu2">Blue</a>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <!-- Tab panes -->
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div id="home" class="container tab-pane active"><br>
      <h3>Red</h3>
      
    </div>
    <div id="menu1" class="container tab-pane fade"><br>
      <h3>Green</h3>
      
    </div>
    <div id="menu2" class="container tab-pane fade"><br>
      <h3>Blue</h3>
      
    </div>
  </div>
      
    </div>
    
   
  </div>
  
  </div>
  <div class="row mr-2 ml-0" style="display:none;" id="mercredi">test</div>
  <div class="row mr-2 ml-0" style="display:none;" id="jeudi">Some content4</div>
  <div class="row mr-2 ml-0" style="display:none;" id="vendredi">Some content5</div>
  <div class="row mr-2 ml-0" style="display:none;" id="samedi">Some content6</div>
  <div class="row mr-2 ml-0" style="display:none;" id="dimanche">Some content6</div>
</div>
```

Comment: anyone help me out this issue its very helpful. I am stuck in here when i click on chekbox2 then red green blue toggle show in above of add new button. I try to achieve but not happen

Comment: https://kapwi.ng/w/DQu7aukF for refrence example link image video

Answer (score 0):

Do NOT wrap the inputs in a div, so you can do with css

#undiCheck:checked ~ #undi {
display: block;
}

Answer (score 0):

First you have replace checkbox to radio button,
i modify your code add some div & change structure of your HTML
add extra some css

i hope this can solve your probleam

```css
    .menu {
    max-width: 400px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
}

.menu a {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000;
  line-height: 1;
}

label {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 0 2px 0;
  padding :12px;
  line-height: 1;
  color :#fff;
  background :#007bbb;
  cursor :pointer;
}

input {
    display: none;
}


.menu .row {
  max-height: 0;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
    -ms-transition: all 0.5s;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s;
    transition: all 0.5s;
}


.accordion:checked ~ #lundi2,
.accordion:checked ~ #mardi2,
.accordion:checked ~ #jeudi2,
.accordion:checked ~ #mercredi2 {
    max-height: unset;
  opacity: 1;
  max-width: 100%;
}


.wrapper {
    display: inline-block;
}


.menu .row {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #9e9e9e;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
}

.menu {
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
    <div class="wrapper">
         <label for="lundi">01</label>
    <input type="radio" name="radio" id="lundi" class="accordion" />
    <div class="row mr-2 ml-0" style="" id="lundi2">
  
      <br>
      <!-- Nav pills -->
      <ul class="nav nav-pills" role="tablist">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="pill" href="#homemade">variant</a>
        </li>
        
      </ul>
      <!-- Tab panes -->
      <div class="tab-content">
        <div id="homemade" class="container tab-pane active"><br>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">ADD NEW</button>
          
        </div>
      </div>
      
    </div>
    
    </div>

    <div class="wrapper">
        <label for="mardi" >2</label>
    <input type="radio" name="radio" id="mardi" class="accordion" />
     <div class="row mr-2 ml-0" style="" id="mardi2">
    <br>
    <!-- Nav pills -->
    <ul class="nav nav-pills" role="tablist">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="pill" href="#home">Colors</a>
      </li>
      
      
    </ul>
    <!-- Tab panes -->
    <div class="tab-content">
      <div id="home" class="container tab-pane active"><br>
        <!-- Nav tabs -->
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="#home">Red</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1">Green</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#menu2">Blue</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <!-- Tab panes -->
        <div class="tab-content">
          <div id="home" class="container tab-pane active"><br>
            <h3>Red</h3>
            
          </div>
          <div id="menu1" class="container tab-pane fade"><br>
            <h3>Green</h3>
            
          </div>
          <div id="menu2" class="container tab-pane fade"><br>
            <h3>Blue</h3>
            
          </div>
        </div>
        
      </div>
      
      
    </div>
    
  </div>
    </div>

    <div class="wrapper">
         <label for="mercredi">3</label>
    <input type="radio" name="radio" id="mercredi" class="accordion" />
     <div class="row mr-2 ml-0" style="" id="mercredi2">test</div>
    </div>

    <div class="wrapper">
         <label for="jeudi">4</label>
    <input type="radio" name="radio" id="jeudi" class="accordion" />
     <div class="row mr-2 ml-0" style="" id="jeudi2">Some content4</div>
    </div>
   

   

   
</div>
```